# AR(1)-process: Conditional distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Consider I have an AR(p)-process $ (X_{t})_{t\in Z  } $, for example the following AR(1)-process:

$$X_{t}=\alpha_{0} + \alpha_{1}X_{t-1}+\epsilon_{t}$$
where $ \epsilon_{t}\sim D(0,\sigma^2) $ is an uncorrelated, zero-mean, finite variance process (White Noise) with distribution function $D$ (e.g. normal distribution).

Given the information set $\Phi_{t-1}$, the conditional distribution of $X_t$ is $$X_t|\Phi_{t-1}\sim D(\alpha_{0} + \alpha_{1}X_{t-1},\sigma^2).$$

1. How do we know that $\epsilon_{t}$ is independent of all past values {$X_{t-1},X_{t-2}...$}? The assumption that $\epsilon_{t}$ is White Noise does not imply its independence of past $X_t$.

So I guess "$\epsilon_{t}$ is independent of {$X_{t-1},X_{t-2}...$}" is just another assumption for AR-processes?

2. Saying that $\epsilon_t$ is independent of the infinite set {$X_{t-1},X_{t-2}...$} means that $\epsilon_t$ is independent of every subset of {$X_{t-1},X_{t-2}...$}?

Comment: Why would the white noise be dependent on the process?

Comment: @Quality If the $\epsilon_t$ is dependent on previous $\epsilon$'s one would expect it to be dependent on previous values of the process, no?

Comment: The definition of white noise is that they ARE independent

Comment: @Quality They explicitly say "uncorrelated" and not independent and this is also the stipulation of many definitions of white noise I've seen. (It's also common to see it require only pairwise independence between the $\epsilon$'s... I confess I've never been sure why all the fuss. I guess it's easier to statistically check the weaker assumptions?)

Comment: In Hamilton: Time Series Analysis, he also refers to the uncorrelated White Noise in the definition of the AR(1)-process

Answer (score 1):

> 1. How do we know that $\epsilon_{t}$ is independent of all past values {$X_{t-1},X_{t-2}...$}? The assumption that $\epsilon_{t}$ is
>      White Noise does not imply its independence of past $X_t$.

"White noise" is sometimes (not always) taken to imply that terms are independent, not just uncorrelated. If $\epsilon_t$ is independent of all previous $\epsilon_{t-n}$ then it *must* also be independent of any function of those variables.

But $X_{t-n}$ can be expressed as an infinite sum involving only $\alpha_{0}$. $\alpha_{1}$, and $\epsilon_{t-n}, \epsilon_{t-n-1}, \epsilon_{t-n-2}, ...$ and hence $\epsilon_t$ must be independent of $X_{t-n}$ for positive $n$.

If we apply only the "uncorrelated" interpretation, then it's definitely *not* true that $\epsilon_t$ is independent of past X-values.

(Trivial example: choose any distribution for $\epsilon$ that is uncorrelated but not independent, and set $\alpha_0 = \alpha_1 = 0$.)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Thanks, I missed that little detail in the OP. Better now?

Comment: The white noise is here gaussian. For a jointly gaussian process, uncorrelatedness implies independence. Hence, the white noise should be assumed to be independent.

(Strictly speaking, it would be possible for the process to be marginally gaussian, but not jointly gaussian - hence uncorrelated would not necessarily mean independent - but I'd bet the author meant jointly gaussian).

Comment: I didn‘t want to restrict the process to be Gaussian, the normal distribution was just an example. But you‘re right, if it‘s jointly Gaussian, then uncorrelatedness would imply independence

Comment: But I have one more question: Is it equivalent to say $\epsilon_t$ are independent of each other <=> $\epsilon_t$ is independent of $\Phi_{t-1}$?

Comment: @Abc123 What exactly is $\Phi_{t-1}$? I don't think you actually defined it.

Comment: Oh yes, you‘re right. $\Phi_{t-1}$ = {$X_{t-1},X_{t-2},...$}, i.e. the set of all past values of $X_t$.

Comment: @Abc123 past values of $X_t$ determine all the past values of $\epsilon_t$ and vice versa, so that's equivalent to asking if "$\epsilon_t$ are independent of each other" <=> "$\epsilon_t$ is independent of all previous $\epsilon$" (assuming an implied "for all $t$" there?).

Comment: All right, so far I know that $\epsilon_t$ is independent of $X_{t-j}$ for all j >= 1, provided that $\epsilon_t$ is a sequence of independent random variables. Does this imply that $\epsilon_t$ is independent of the entire set $\Phi_{t-1}$ = {$X_{t-1}, X_{t-2},...$}? I‘m struggling with that, because in general, if we have a random variable $X$ and a random vector $Y=(Y_1,Y_2)$, pairwise independence between $X$ and $Y_1$ and between $X$ and $Y_2$ does not imply independence between $X$ and $Y$. Or am I on a completely wrong track?